# Which is more secure: develop a mobile app in its Native language or using cross-platform UI?

Tags: appsec, mobile, source-code

I am just wondering if there are benefits from a security perspective to develop a mobile App either as native app or as a cross-platform UI app, in particular Rhodes? I need to develop an application and from security perspective i am wondering if i gain any additional security in going one way over the other.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?  Which platform?  What do you mean by cross-platform UI app?

Comment: Rhodes added as a cross-platform Native Framework

Comment: Just curious, what did you think `[security-theater]` means? I removed it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two main things to watch out for:

- *you* will make fewer mistakes in the environment with which you're more accustomed. If you understand secure coding in, e.g. C# better than Objective-C, then Monotouch might be better for you than Cocoa Touch.
- the combination "your code + operating system" has a smaller attack surface than "your code + third party library + operating system".

In almost all cases, the contribution from the first factor is far greater than that from the second.

Comment: +1, very good in pointing out the conflicting considerations needed to make an intelligent tradeoff *for him*. But one question, are there no mobile frameworks that specifically add security features / secure APIs?

Comment: @avid none I've ever come across.